# Possible to add more suggestions to the "How to Ask" box?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When any user clicks the "Ask a Question" button, the page gives a helpful "How to Ask" box on the right side with some suggestions about what makes a good question.  Can we add additional information to this box for SharePoint Questions?  More specifically the answers to most questions can vary significantly depending on whether the OP is using SharePoint Online or which particular version of on-Prem SharePoint Server they are using, or in Modern- or Classic-  mode.  Yet I would say easily 90% of the questions fail to include this info in their post.

I find myself making the same comment on so many questions asking them to provide this detail.

Can we add this info to the "How to Ask" box?

I found a meta thread from [nine years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83040/can-a-community-edit-its-how-to-ask-page) saying it is not possible, but Nine years ago?  That's like an eternity in software development, surely this is a feature that could be implemented by now?

Seems to me that if each StackExchange Community could customize it's own "How to Ask" page, the overall quality of the questions, and our ability to help would increase significantly.